# SQL Server: difference in days for two dates in separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, datediff, case-when

I am using SQL Server 2012 and working an a report currently that is asking me to find the difference in days between two dates.

Basically, for a particular `ReportID`, I'm trying to find the difference in days between the (`ReportCompletedDate` when the `ReportType = 'PaperReceived'`) - (`ReportCompletedDate` when the `ReportType = 'Form Completed'`)

I tried to give some records below...

```
ReportID   ReportType       ReportCompletedDate  
-------------------------------------------------
450        PaperReceived      9/5/2013
450        Form Completed     8/13/2013
451        PaperReceived      9/7/2013
451        Form Completed     7/12/2013
452        PaperReceived      10/6/2013
452        Form Completed     3/13/2013
```

So, for `ReportID = 450` for example, I want to get `9/5/2013 - 8/13/2013` in days.

If anyone also knows how to do this for calendar days and business days, that would be awesome...but at least calendar days should be fine.

I'm not sure how to go about this, usually when the two dates are in line, it's easier for me to figure out, but not sure how to go about it when the dates are in separate rows. Any advice would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a self join to make it appear on "one line".  Like this:

```
SELECT DateDiff(day,BASE.ReportCompleteDate, FORM.ReportCompleteDate) as Diff
FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY BASE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY FORM ON BASE.ReportId = FORM.ReportID AND FORM.ReportType = 'Form Completed'
WHERE BASE.ReportType = 'PaperRecieved'
```

Comment: You may have to add the datepart as 'day' to DATEDIFF statement

Comment: @AbdullahDibas thanks -- yeah been a while since I used datediff

Comment: @Hogan Thank you, this was what I needed!! Also ty Abdullah.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below one of the approach...

```
SELECT RCVD.REPORTID
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, RCVD.REPORTCOMPLETEDDATE, CMPLD.REPORTCOMPLETEDDATE) DAY_DIFF
FROM (
    SELECT REPORTID
        , REPORTCOMPLETEDDATE
    FROM REPORTS
        WHERE REPORTTYPE = 'PaperReceived'
) RCVD
    JOIN (
    SELECT REPORTID
        , REPORTCOMPLETEDDATE
    FROM REPORTS
        WHERE REPORTTYPE = 'Form Completed'
) CMPLD
    ON RCVD.REPORTID = CMPLD.REPORTID
```

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this as well to get strictly business days instead of calendar days?