# SQL Azure Calculate End to Start in Days Across Two Rows For Rooms

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have a table that has Container/Room IDs.  Each Row has an ID for the Container/Room and a Start and End date time.  I need to calculate for the containers that have multiple rows the time between the end date and the start date of the next row.

Sample Data:
[image]

The desired output would be a 3rd column with the Diff in Days between the END to the Start of the next row - when the room number has multiple rows.  If there is only one row the desired output would be 0.

I looked at [SQL Server: difference in days for two dates in separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986643/sql-server-difference-in-days-for-two-dates-in-separate-rows) but this uses only one date column and I'm struggling to figure out how to calculate the diff across the rows when there are multiple rows for a room.

Comment: going forward please paste expected result and actual restult as text

Comment: Will do, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `datediff()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, enddt,
                lead(startdt) over (partition by room order by startdt)
               ) as diff
from t;
```